# Multiply mode in CSS?

Tags: css, background-blend-mode, mix-blend-mode

In Photoshop if you import a JPG image with a white background into a document with a blue `background`, you can make the white `background` of the image disappear by setting the image to "multiply" mode.

Can I do exactly the same thing with CSS alone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In CSS you can use [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode)

> The `mix-blend-mode` CSS property describes how an element content
>   should blend with the content of the element that is below it and the
>   element's background.

#### Snippet

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200) no-repeat 0 0 / cover
}
img {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/300" />
```

Or you can use [`background-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-blend-mode)

> The `background-blend-mode` CSS property describes how the element's
>   background images should blend with each other and the element's
>   background color.

#### Snippet

```css
div {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background: url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8543/br.png'),url('https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8545/tr.png');
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

IE doesn't support both, see Support [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-mixblendmode) and [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [background-blend-mode](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/) but [only in Chrome and Firefox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode).

According to the CSS Tricks article, the code looks like this:

```
.blended {
    background-image: url(face.jpg);
    background-color: red;
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes...sort of...

The question is a little vague but can we remove the white 'part' of an image and let us see the background color of the element behind it?

Yes we can...with `mix-blend-mode`.

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/penguin-clip-art-penguin_clip_art_7050.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Note: this is only showing that background of the element ***behind*** the div holding the image....nothing happens if you add a background color to the wrapping div.

For that you might need yet another wrapper.

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
div.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  background: red;
}
div.child {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/penguin-clip-art-penguin_clip_art_7050.jpg" alt="" />
  </div>

</div>
```

or perhaps as a background to a pseudo-element:

```css
body {
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  margin: 1em auto;
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
}
div.child::before {
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(http://images.clipartpanda.com/penguin-clip-art-penguin_clip_art_7050.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="child"></div>
```